# How to open a doc and video file inside my react-native app without using any 3rd party software?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I am building an app that can open any kind of document inside it like pdf, image, doc, video, and HTML without using any 3rd party software like VLC, google docs etc. I'm, able to open pdf and image file inside my app but could not find any solution for doc and video file.
Note:- All files are in base64 format.

Comment: Did you tried https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video for video ?

Comment: I tried but it,s not able to play the video which is in base64 format.

Comment: You have to convert it to blob format

Comment: How to do it, can you give me some reference?